# Windows 10 switching between language (Shift+alt) popup

Tags: windows-10

Since recently my PC using Windows 10 ver 2004 build 1904 Started showing this bar when I press Shift+Alt to switch between languages. (The picture is not from my PC its an example). I tried several steps to fix it and none worked for me I even sent a feedbag ticket to Microsoft. I jsut wonder does anybody else have the same problem (Well its a feature) and how did you remove it(if it ever bothered you).

When i press Alt+Shift it doesnt show up but it didnt either back when I used Shift + alt[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzq4.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Have you tried to remove the language pack you no longer wish to be installed?

Comment: I just want to ask if its posible to remove the popup but still be able to switch between both languages with shift+alt (English and Bulgarian)

Comment: You should edit your question because it's currently not clear.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear question man it's jsut that I am really trying to solve this problem and it gives me pain in the eyes when this window shows up I tried everything even did a feedbag ticket to microsoft. I mean if anyone knows how to disable it pls

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot disable that particular feature, if you really don't want to see it, remove the other language pack.

Comment: Ok I did a really long research and I do agree that I cannot remove the feature. I guess I have to get used to it.